# Insert multiple rows at once in node postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a `users` array of type `User`:

```
type User = {
  name: string
  surname: string
}
```

How do I insert **in one go** (in one query) all users?

Now i'm mapping over `users` and `await`ing with `Promise.all`, but I guess there's a better way:

```
const promises = users.map(user => {
  return client.query(`
    INSERT INTO users (name, surname)
    VALUE ($1, $2);
  `, [user.name, user.surname])
})
await Promise.all(promises)
```

I've seen examples with hardcoded values inserting multiple elements but not with *dynamic* values.

```
INSERT INTO users (name, surname)
VALUES
  ('John', 'Doe'),
  ('Jane', 'Doe');
```

Comment: This may be helpful: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/957